# How to retrieve website URL from contact info in Wordpress using PHP

Tags: php, wordpress

I did my search and all the solutions I found is for getting the author's url on the website, but I need to get the website url that the user input in his contact info.

[Illustration for what I need](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NYvvH.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a user data not meta data, so go with:

```
get_userdata(get_current_user_id())->user_url; // or whatever user id you want
```

Comment: Hi Angel, this code retrieve the user link on wordpress, not the website he/she saved in his contact info, can you help me get the website in the contact info?

Comment: this gets the website ! I can confirm that ! Open up your phpadmin or whatever and check you wp_users table there is  a column -> user_url. This is exactly what you've showed on the image and this is how you get it !